# How to add the name of the json file while using cat & select through multiple json files

Tags: json, jq, filenames

I'm new to JQ and work on an Events Data Set. I select specific events (shot.type.id==88) from a folder with multiple json files after concatenating them. Then I choose some variables of interest (id, index, player_id,...). See the following code:

```sh
cat * | jq -r '.[] | select(.shot.type.id==88) | {id:.id, index:.index, player_id:.player.id,striker_name:.player.name} '
```

Concerning the output: I'd like to add the name of the json file, from which the event is taken. I've tried input_filename within the "{}" but had no success. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Using `cat *` destroys any filename information that exists. Modify your pipeline to

```
jq -r '...' *
```

and `input_filename` will evaluate to the current filename.